# Sharepoint REST API Call Status 403 FORBIDDEN

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint

I have need to update or create new objects in Sharepoint lists through REST Api.  My REST calls which create new items or edit existing items are returning **Status 403: FORBIDDEN** and it is not apparent to me why. The user has all the access needed to edit and read lists.  How can I proceed and get these REST calls to go through?

```
//update current item
$.ajax({
    url: "/sitename/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('metricList')/items(" + results[i].Id + ")",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.Data.iconMetricsListItem'
        },
        'numClicks': temp
    }),
    headers: {
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }
});


//create new item
$.ajax({
    url:"/sitename/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('metricList')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this running on the same server as sharepoint?  If not, it's considered cross-domain and you need to make sure it is set up accordingly.  Sometimes its as easy as adding 'callback=?' into the URL.

Comment: This function will be triggered from a Sharepoint page by a user with proper permissions. Does this require a cross-domain call? I have never used Cross-Domain calls before, but then again I've only READ with REST before, never written

Comment: Based on you comment, it shouldn't be cross domain.  Your code looks correct to me so I am not sure what is going on. It is almost word for word what I have used with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your authorization header. If that is not sent as part of the request you will always get a 403 status code, even if you have a valid request digest header.